# Passing data to AVCapturePhoto on macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, avfoundation

Usually if you want to use AVCapturePhoto you do something like this:

```
func capturePhoto() {
   let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
   photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
}
```

Then when the photo is processed, `photoOutput` method is called:

```
internal func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
}
```

Question:
Is it possible to pass custom data to photoOutput via `.capturePhoto`? `.metadata` is only accessible on iOS and everytime I set a value with the `.value()` method I get

```
[General] [<AVCapturePhotoSettings 0x600003882080> valueWithUniqueID:inPropertyWithKey:]: lookup of unknown key: 'key'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best and easiest method is to use some other object as a `delegate` for the photo capture and also always create a new delegate instance for each capture action. This way you can pass additional data to the delegate object on `init` that you can use in the `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:)` method.

I can highly recommend checking out the [AVCam sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app) from Apple. There they are doing exactly that.